Pyomo Mixed Integer Programming : how to turn a binary variable equal to 1 if values of a variable exceed a certain threshold for the first time?
I want a binary variable, $inv_year$, to indicate the investment year, i.e., the year where the investment variable, $I$, turns greater than zero for the first time. Both variables ($inv_year$ and $I$) have two indices, time $t$ and project $i$.
In theory, the variable $inv_year[i,t]$ should equal to 1 for the minimum of time $t$ when I[i,t] is greater than 0. It should turn 1 once for each project $i$ to indicate the investment year for that project.
I am using the Big M method in Pyomo, but right now the binary variable, $inv_\year$, turns 1 always when the variable $I$ turns greater than zero. Therefore, the binary investment year variable equals 1 multiple times, rather than only once for each project.
Is there a ways to adjust the Big M method to work like this or do I have to use a different method for this purpose?
Right now, my solution looks as follows:
#First constraint, Big-M method for binary variable inv_year 
def bigM_constraint1(model, i, t):
    lhs_1 = model.inv_year[i,t]
    rhs_1 = model.I[i,t]
    return lhs_1<=rhs_1

#add the rule to the model as a constraint
model.BigM_Constraint1 = Constraint(model.project_type, model.time, rule=bigM_constraint1)

#Second constraint, Big-M method for binary variable inv_year 
def bigM_constraint2(model, i, t):
    lhs_2 = model.I[i,t]
    rhs_2 = model.M[i] * model.inv_year[i,t]
    return lhs_2<=rhs_2

#add the rule to the model as a constraint
model.BigM_Constraint2 = Constraint(model.project_type, model.time, rule=bigM_constraint2)


It's certainly possible; however, the difficulty of doing this varies based on a lot of things including whether the year selectors are optimisation objectives, and whether the optimisation variables are binary or continuous.

@Reinderien thanks for your answer! The optimisation or decision variables are the investment variables, I[i,t], which determine the investment amount in a given year into a given project, and they are continuous variables. The binary investment year variables are not the decision variables. They depend on the investment variables as specified by the big M constraints.

Please edit your question to describe these details and include the relevant code.
